# Restricting some sudoer users's printer behaviours

Tags: printing, sudo, cups-lpd

I tried modifying `/etc/cups/cupsd.config` to restrict some sudoer users' behavior on adding printers. However, the sudoer users are actually in @SYSTEM group. If I move some sudoer users from the @SYSTEM group, the corresponding sudoer users will lose the sudo privileges. It seems not easy to restrict some sudoer users's adding printer behaviors.

Comment: `sudo` means "Super User DO" so you cannot restrict anything a sudoer does once they have sudo access.

Comment: @Terrance. Thanks. Maybe I should put current some sudoer users to other non-sudoer groups.